# What is the best way for building a simple data table in ASP.NET with few extra features?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

What is the most recommended way to build the following table in a web application (asp.net):
[image]

The main header should contain a checkbox which allows to select/deselect all the items in the table. Also when clicking on the header titles (Name, Column 2, etc..) the data should be sorted asc/desc accordingly.

The sub headers should also contain a checkbox which allows to select/deselect all the items in the current sub table. Also each sub header title should contain the number of items in the sub title (for example "(5)").

Also each sub header contains an arrow to collapse/expand the data inside.

Is it possible to build such a table using repeater? what is the best way to build such a table considering I might use it in other places and I want it to be reusable (work with different titles for example).

Comment: Take a look at https://editor.datatables.net/manual/net/mvc they have a great javascript library and integration for asp.net apps.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do that is to render a simple HTML table, 
add then add functionality with [datatable](https://datatables.net/) plugin

Your js code is simple:

```
$("table").datatable();
```

It will add order and search functionality to your table.

Just remember to add **thead** to your table, because datatable will not work without `<head>` and `</head>` markers